# Facebook Login redirects to localhost

Tags: java, facebook, spring-social

I'm working on a website, which uses the Facebook Login with Spring Social. Currently I playing around with the [example](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-social-samples/tree/master/spring-social-quickstart-3.0.x) for version 3.

On localhost this works as intended. Online however, I get the error message that the redirect URI is invalid. The `Site URL` in the Facebook app is defined as `http://subdomain.domain.net/myapp/`. The redirect_uri Facebook sends is `http://localhost:8080/myapp/signin` (taken from the URL error page parameter). This is the configuration I first used.

I already tried to create a new Facebook app, in case Facebook didn't update the configuration properly. Also I tried to add to the Spring Social `ConnectController` the application URL. Every time I get the same error.

Comment: Sounds like that should work - if it is still referencing a redirect URL that you only referenced in the original app settings, then it would sound like facebook is just taking a while propogating the change to the servers - however, if you also registered a completely different app on FB (and added the updated key/secret to the properties and restarted your app) then that is very strange.  I assume you entered "domain.net" for the App Domain setting, and only ticked the "Website with Facebook Login" option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I made a simple configuration mistake. I thought it was sufficient to configure the `ConnectController`, but I missed the `ProviderSignInController`. Like here in the [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-social/docs/1.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/#signin_using)